# Android - How can i make my circular App logo bigger?

Tags: android, icons

I'm using a circular PNG for my app logo. But when i test this on my cellphone, it looks a little bit smaller than the other circular icons. Can you help me?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html look for Using configuration qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix the edges of the image with borders and create the image accordingly.

Hope it helps.